# How to check if checkbox is checked in controller and add the value to table?

Tags: html, laravel

I have a survey form and I need to put the value in one column based on checkbox value.

My input form for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1" />
<label for="chk[]">Prijava</label>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated=$request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'nullable'
        ]);
        if(Input::get('chk')==="1"){
            $validated['prijava']=1;
        }
        else{
            $validated['prijava']=0;
        }
        return Survey::create($validated);
    }
```

I need the 'prijava' column to be 1 if checkbox is check or 0 if not. I always get 0 and if I change code in else to for example 2, it will add 2 in column. I also put 'prijava' column to be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Input` class to check if checkbox is checked or not. Since you already have `Request` instance, check it like this:

```
if($request->chk === "1"){
     $validated['prijava']=1;
}
 else{
     $validated['prijava']=0;
 }
```

Didn't test this, but it should get you desired output. Let me know if you get any errors .

Comment: Can you do `dd($request)` before your validation, and paste the output?

Comment: How can I dd in store method in controller because it redirects me when I create a survey?

Comment: Add dd() method on top of your function.

Comment: When I put dd the survey won't even store to database.

Comment: It wont, I just wanted to see what do you get in your $request

Comment: I'm checking inspect element and every time I check the checkbox there's no value for 'prijava', only if it's unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->has('chk')
```

will return true if the checkbox is checked, and false if not.

Answer (score 0):

first remove value attribute like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" />
```

then in your store method update your code to :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated=$request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'description'=>'nullable'
        ]);
        if($request->has('chk')){
            $validated['prijava']=1;
        }
        else{
            $validated['prijava']=0;
        }
        return Survey::create($validated);
    }
```

i think this works well

Comment: It doesn't. :/ Still 0.